# custom highlight function doesn't work with special characters - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

I have been testing my React-native App's front-end and found some issue. 
There is a SearchBar that highlights the text in the Search result as shown below.

[image]

But when i try to search **"( )[ ] ! + , . & %"** and many more the character is displayed in the search result but not highlighted. I am guessing this has something to do with RegExp.

[image]

The Highlight function code:

```
escape = function( value ) {
    return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$%#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}


getHighlightedText(text){       // Highlight logic 
    const {value} = this.props;
    
    if(value == "" || value == null || value == 0){
      return <Text> {text} </Text>
    }
    else{
    const words = value.split(/\s+/g).filter(word => word.length);
    const pattern = words.join('|');
    const tex = escape(pattern);
    const re = new RegExp(tex, 'gi')
    const children = [];
    let before, highlighted, match, pos = 0;
    const matches = text.match(re);

    if(matches != null){
    for( match of matches ){
      match = re.exec(text)
      if(pos < match.index) {
        before = text.substring(pos, match.index);
        if(before.length){
          children.push(before)
        }
      }
      highlighted = <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'coral'}} key={match.index + match[0].length}>{match[0]}</Text> 
      children.push(highlighted);    
      pos = match.index + match[0].length;
    }
  }

    if(pos < text.length){
      const last = text.substring(pos);
      children.push(last);
    }
    return <Text>{children}</Text>
  }






render() {

<Text> {value !== "" ? this.getHighlightedText(text) : text} </Text>

}
```

I want all the characters to be highlighted.
Any suggestion would be great to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is in the first line of your code!

Why you're using "escape" function? you're removing special characters in your code before highlight

```
escape = function( value ) {
    return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$%#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

This is a cleaner version and better version of your code :

```
const Highlighted = ({text = '', highlight = ''}) => {
  if (!highlight.trim()) {
    return <Text>{text}</Text>;
  }
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${_.escapeRegExp(highlight)})`, 'gi');
  const parts = text.split(regex);
  return (
    <Text>
      {parts
        .filter(part => part)
        .map((part, i) =>
          regex.test(part) ? (
            <Text style={{backgroundColor: '#fcf8e3'}} key={i}>
              {part}
            </Text>
          ) : (
            <Text key={i}>{part}</Text>
          ),
        )}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

and then

```
<Highlighted
          text={allTextsHere}
          highlight={
            searchTermHere}
        />
```

Comment: if i do not use escape function then when i type "( ) or ! or + or [ ]" in my SearchBar it throws this error "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses"

Comment: use this:
new RegExp(`(${_.escapeRegExp(highlight)})`, 'gi');